# Using jQuery autosuggest plugin with Geonames

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, autosuggest, geonames

I am relatively new to jquery, and am trying to figure out how to get this autosuggest plugin to work with geonames (returns location info). There is a similar example of it working with the jquery autocomplete here http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp but I can't get it to work with autosuggest. Below is what I'm trying but I get nothing for the results and this browser console error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'geonames.adminName1' of undefined.

```
$("#location2").autoSuggest("http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON", {selectedItemProp: "geonames.adminName1", searchObjProps: "geonames.adminName1", selectedValuesProp : "geonames.name"});
```

The json returned from geonames looks like this:

```
{"totalResultsCount":29,"geonames":[{"countryName":"United States","adminCode1":"UT","fclName":"city, village,...","countryCode":"US","lng":-111.6946475,"fcodeName":"populated place","toponymName":"Orem","fcl":"P","name":"Orem","fcode":"PPL","geonameId":5779334,"lat":40.2968979,"adminName1":"Utah","population":88328},{"countryName":"United States","adminCode1":"UT","fclName":"country, state, region,...","countryCode":"US","lng":-111.69912,"fcodeName":"administrative division","toponymName":"City of Orem","fcl":"A","name":"City of Orem","fcode":"ADMD","geonameId":7174024,"lat":40.2987069,"adminName1":"Utah","population":88328}]}
```

If I manually copy the JSON into a var called data and then use it for the source like this it works:

```
$("#location2").autoSuggest("data.geonames", {selectedItemProp: "adminName1", searchObjProps: "adminName1", selectedValuesProp : "name"});
```

I would also like to know if it would be possible to combine more than 1 value when a result is selected, like adminName1 + name?

Please and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the remote jsonp response on autocomplete works with the $.ajax() method.
Review the documentation on $.ajax().

On success, the ajax method can pass the data to $.map() and then you can do whatever you want with the data (print it out or put it on the DOM)